# Reset color values to default after change- Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am working with styling the link which are formatted within ul/li table(materialized css).

```
    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed"  >
  <li >
    <a class="link-text-1" appHighlight>
      <span>Parent-alone</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li >
    <a class="link-text-2" appHighlight>
      <span>Parent</span>
    </a>
    <ul id="inner" class="inner"  >
      <li >
        <a class="child-link-1" appHighlight>
          <span>Child-1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li >
        <a class="child-link-2" appHighlight>
          <span >Child-2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add the change color to each clicked link text. When on of link is clicked (active), all not clicked should have default color (so previously clicked should reset to default). I need to do it with Angular 5 directives and I do not know how to reset state of not clicked links. Is there any Angular 5 way to do this?

my directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective  {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('click') clickedLink() {
    this.highlight('red');
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.color = color;
  }

}
```